# Back button using history in Electron

Tags: javascript, html, electron

So I've got two pages on my electron project, and I'd like to put a button on the second page that goes back to the first. I thought I could easily just use the following code to be able to go back:

html:

```
<button onclick="goBack()">Go Back</button>
```

script.js:

```
function goBack() {
  window.history.back();
}
```

But this doesn't seem to work in Electron. Is there a way to get `history.back();` to work?

Comment: Try `window.history.go(-1)` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History_API

Comment: @LoveenDyall didn't work :(